# react native show the other component depends on the picker choice

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to show the hidden picker if the first picker has choose something.

How to show some component when picker changes

```
{
              this.state.showme ?
                <View>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.PickerClearance}
                    style={styles.pickercont}
                    onValueChange={handlePickerChange}>
                    {/* onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ PickerClearance: itemValue })}> */}
                    <Picker.Item label='Certificate Type' value='0' />
                    <Picker.Item label="Barangay Certificate" value="barangay certificate" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Barangay Clearance" value="barangay clearance" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>
                :
                <View>
                  <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.PickerClearance}
                    style={styles.pickercont}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ PickerClearance: itemValue })}>
                    <Picker.Item label='Type of Certificates' value='0' />
                    <Picker.Item label="Barangay Certificate" value="barangay certificate" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Barangay Clearance" value="barangay clearance" />
                  </Picker>
                </View>
            }
```

Comment: and when selected you want to hide first one?

Comment: Please define you question and description correctly. I could get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [Modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal). You could design the `Modal` in such a way that it looks like a picker. By using the boolean state value you can prompt the modal anytime you want. Elements in the modal could be structured in terms of a [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist). If you want a sample code do comment.